# Route from JMS topic to bean does not retry

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I've got a route which is defined in Java in a route builder as follows:

```
from("jms:topic:trigger?maxConcurrentConsumers=1")
        .autoStartup(true)
        .beanRef("someProcessorBeen");
```

This has worked well for a few years.

However, under certain circumstances I want to be able to throw a specific 'retry' exception in the java processor bean, so that the same exchange is re-sent to the Bean.

I've tried adding `&transacted=true` to the JMS topic reference URI in the 'from' part, but I just get an ERROR log message from the `DefaultErrorHandler` which says "Failed delivery for ......" when I throw my retry Exception.

I've also tried adding:

```
onException(MyRetryException.class).maximumRedeliveries(10);
```

Before the `from` route definition, but the route doesn't seem to get created, as the route does not process any topic messages.

Note that this is all running within an OSGi environment, with ActiveMQ handling the JMS stuff.

---

UPDATE: OK, I found that adding the following in the route builder gives me what I want:

```
    RedeliveryPolicyDefinition redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicyDefinition();
    // Set redelivery policy so it retries every 5 seconds for 10 minutes,
    // then log an error when the retries have been exhausted
    redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries(120)
            .redeliveryDelay(5000)
            .logExhausted(true)
            .retriesExhaustedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.ERROR);

    onException(MyRetryException.class)
            .setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
```

So the question now is: Is this the *correct* way to achieve this?

Comment: If you have a copy of the Camel in Action book then it has a full chapter on error handling and another on transactions - there you have answers for all your questions and you would be much better at your work with Camel

Comment: Take care. You configured the Camel redelivery, not a JMS redelivery. Get a copy of the book @claus-ibsen suggested in his comment to read about the important difference between the two redelivery types.